# Convert a .txt file to Json c, but some Attributes are empty

Tags: arrays, c, json

So I write a c-program, which shall read out a .txt file and create a json out of it.
The structure of the .txt file:

```
ADDR               AID CHAN TXRATE RXRATE RSSI MINRSSI MAXRSSI IDLE  TXSEQ  RXSEQ  CAPS      ACAPS     ERP    STATE MAXRATE(DOT11) HTCAPS ASSOCTIME    IEs   MODE                   PSMODE
da:49:00:1c:52:20    1  128 780M    433M   52      30      68   15      0   65535    EP         0          b              0            AWPS 00:43:58     RSN WME IEEE80211_MODE_11AC_VHT80   1 
5a:38:22:ae:8f:4a    2  128 780M      6M   57      44      60    4      0   65535    EP         0          b              0            AWPS 00:01:58     RSN WME IEEE80211_MODE_11AC_VHT80   1
```

These are some device data which got sended. The first line ("the header line") gets ignored.
The json shall look like this:

```
 "devicedatas":  [{
                        "ADDR": "5a:38:22:ae:8f:4a",
                        "AID":  "1",
                        "CHAN": "124",
                        "TXRATE":       "780M",
                        "RXRATE":       "6M",
                        "RSSI": "56",
                        "MINRSSI":      "21",
                        "MAXRSSI":      "68",
                        "IDLE": "5",
                        "TXSEQ":        "0",
                        "RXSEQ":        "65535",
                        "CAPS": "EP",
                        "ACAPS":        "0",
                        "ERP":  "b",
                        "STATE":        "0",
                        "MAXRATE(DOT11)":       "AWPS",
                        "HTCAPS":       "00:53:17",
                        "ASSOCTIME":    "RSN",
                        "IEs":  "WME",
                        "MODE": "IEEE80211_MODE_11AC_VHT80",
                        "PSMODE":       "1"
                }, {
                        "ADDR": "a2:35:25:67:23:e9",
                        "AID":  "1",
                        "CHAN": "124",
                        "TXRATE":       "866M",
                        "RXRATE":       "585M",
                        "RSSI": "43",
                        "MINRSSI":      "39",
                        "MAXRSSI":      "44",
                        "IDLE": "15",
                        "TXSEQ":        "0",
                        "RXSEQ":        "65535",
                        "CAPS": "EP",
                        "ACAPS":        "0",
                        "ERP":  "b",
                        "STATE":        "0",
                        "MAXRATE(DOT11)":       "AWPS",
                        "HTCAPS":       "00:01:57",
                        "ASSOCTIME":    "RSN",
                        "IEs":  "WME",
                        "MODE": "IEEE80211_MODE_11AC_VHT80",
                        "PSMODE":       "1"
                }]
```

So my Code searches for every attribute the beginning of the word and then the end. Its every time in the right so i save it in an 2D char array and the add the parts to the Json.
My Code where the file gets opened and read out (that works):

```
FILE *fp;
char data[MAXCHAR];
char macarray[MAXDEVICES][18];

fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
  printf("Could not open file %s", filename);
  return 1;
}

int i = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < MAXDEVICES; j++)
{
  macarray[j][0] = '\0';
}
        
while (fgets(data, sizeof(data), fp))
{
    /* note that fgets don't strip the terminating \n, checking its
     presence would allow to handle lines longer that sizeof(line) */
   data[MAXCHAR-1] = '\0';
   if (i > 0 && data[0] != '\0' && data[0] != '\n')
   {
       strcpy(macarray[i - 1], data);
       createDeviceData(stats, macarray[i - 1]);
       cJSON_AddItemToArray(devices, devicedata = cJSON_CreateObject());
       addStatsToDevicedata(devicedata, stats);
   }
   i++;
}
fclose(fp);
```

My code for finding the Begin of a word, finding the blank (end of a word) and where the device Data gets written in the 2D char Array stats.

```
// finding the beginning of the next word in a Char
void findWordBegin(char *array, int *next)
{
    char a = array[0];
    (*next) = 0;
    
    while (a == ' ' && a != '\0')
    {
        ++(*next);
        a = array[*next];
    }
}

// Finding the spot of the next blank
void findBlank(char *array, int *next)
{
    char a  =  array[0];
    (*next) = 0;

    while (a != ' ' && a != '\0')
    {
        ++(*next);

        a = array[*next];    
    }
}

// stats shall be filled with the stats of the Device
// array contains all data of the Device
void createDeviceData(char **stats, char *array)
{
    int next;
    int statsNumber = 0;
    
    while (statsNumber <= 20)
    {
        findWordBegin(array, &next);
        array += sizeof(char) * (next);
        findBlank(array, &next);
        strncpy(stats[statsNumber], array, next);

        *(stats[statsNumber] + next) = '\0'; 
        array += sizeof(char) * next;
        ++statsNumber;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the attribute STATE can be empty (also other attributes), so the json doesn't get created right. The number of blankets can be changeable in the .txt file. So it has to be a general solution.
What is an effective Method, that in this case it gets ignored?

Also IEs has a blanket in its information.
So my next question is how can be detected, that in the information is a blanket?

Or is there a more general/better way to collect the attributes?